# How can I get the nearest entity in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, math

I have:

```
array = [{
  'id': <an id like -45283etc>,
  'x': 7,
  'y': 10,
  'z': 5
},
{
  'id': <random id, too>,
  'x': 19,
  'y': 6,
  'z': 4
},
{
  'id': <random id, too>,
  'x': 2,
  'y': -7,
  'z': -5
}
]
```

array[0] is the player

How can i know which of the Entities (array[1] or array[2]) is the closest to array[0]?

```
for(var closest = 1, var i = 1; i < array.length; i++){
  if(array[i] is closer to player than closest){
    var closest = array[i]
  }
}
return array[i]
```

What do I have to write in the if-statement?

Comment: This question is not answerable unless you define "closer". `array[1]` is trivially closer by index. If you want to compare the actual objects properties as numeric values, you'll have to decide which properties you want to use and if you want an L1,L2, or L-infinity norm.

Comment: Question is not clear. **Closer** based on `x,y,z` value?

Comment: @Paulpro No.  It wasn't right.  I deleted that comment.  At the very least, you need to first build an offset (the x,y, and z coordinates of array[0]) and use them to offset the calculation (difference of the values).

Comment: This is more of a math problem, isn't it? This answer may help http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42640/calculate-distance-in-3d-space

Comment: @JosephMarikle I answered the question, under the assumption that you were on the right track about what the OP meant by "closest". It seems reasonable, given the property names, `x`, `y`, and `z`.

Comment: @Paulpro I have an 3-Dimansional World and want to know which of my Entities is the nearest to the player (array[0]). There are also negative xyz values

Comment: @user224050 That is what the code in my answer below does. At the end of it `closest` will be the index in the array of the closest point to `array[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to treat them as points and by "closest" you mean using an L2-norm (Euclidean distance), you could use:

```
var minDistanceSquared = Infinity;
for(var closest = 1, i = 1; i < array.length; i++){
    var distanceSquared = Math.abs( 
      Math.pow( array[i].x - array[0].x, 2 ) +
      Math.pow( array[i].y - array[0].y, 2 ) + 
      Math.pow( array[i].z - array[0].z, 2 )
    );
    if ( distanceSquared < minDistanceSquared ) {
        closest = i;
        minDistanceSquared = distanceSquared;
    }
}
```

This is based of the pseudo code loop in your question and relies on the player being at index `0`.

Comment: Definitely better than my cobbled thoughts on a solution from a math standpoint.  One suggestion I would make **as an alternative solution** in addition to this code is to use the array sort method with a callback instead of simply looping over them like OP was trying to do.  It might not be what OP asked for, but it could still be useful in this scenario to instead of simply returning the closest one, to sort the array or a copy of the array by distance to the player.  Regardless, nice solution.